# Insert a line break in specific choice in sharepoint choice column

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, choice-field

I'm trying to do something a bit special with SharePoint choice columns. I'm on SharePoint Online and have access to InfoPath Designer and SharePoint Designer.

I have a choice column where I have enabled multiple choices. The problem I got is that the text in my choices are quite long.

For example "Allows access to shared resources in the Web site so that the users can access an item within the site. Designed to be combined with fine-grained permissions to give users access to a specific list, document library, folder, list item, or document, without giving them access to the entire site. Cannot be customized or deleted."

That's one choice. And because of its length, I have an horizontal scrollbar in my form which is pretty ugly.

When I try to insert a line break to prevent the scroll bar to appear, it creates a new choice with a new checkbox...

What I want is to display "nicely" each of my choices, without scroll bar.

Like that : 
Choice 1 - Allows access to shared resources in the Web site so that the users can access an item within the site. 
Designed to be combined with fine-grained permissions to give users access to a specific list, document library, folder, list item, or document, without giving them access to the entire site. 
Cannot be customized or deleted

Choice 2 -  etc.

Hope I was clear and you can help !

Comment: You could change the display from a choicefield to radio button, and then have shorter internal values when selected. http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/infopath-more-than-two-radio-buttons-in-sharepoint-2013-20951.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it's not my question. Actually in my InfoPath I have three choices with one checkbox each (I want to enable multiple choices).
But the text of each of them is too long for the box. So I want to "wrap" it as it's wrap when you comment in this comment section. 
Or, if not possible, to insert a line break to wrap it manually.